# Trying to develop mods for minecraft, but can't get the SetupdecompWorkspace.bat to work

Tags: java, eclipse

First of all, this is my first ever post on stack exchange so let me know if this belongs in a different section.

Anyway, I've been wanting to get into modding minecraft so I downloaded JDK, Forge MDK and eclipse neon. After exacting files to a separate folder, I created a path variable and a Setup Workspace.bat file. In that file I typed

gradlew setupDecompWorkspace && gradlew eclipse

After this, I ran it and it got to 56%, or decompilemc. It stayed there for about 6 minutes before the console crashed. I assumed there was an error so I researched it and tried to fix it by adding more RAM to the gradle.properties. That didn't work either, so I continued researching for about an hour, and finally found something that made it go pass the decompilemc, only to break again at recompilemc

Have any of you ever encountered this problem? If so, how did you fix it? Any answer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is this section: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/
But I am not sure whether this question should be post here or there.
Thought it is possible you already knew that.

Comment: This video seems to work https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKUQx8nP6o4

Answer (score 0):

If this is your first time starting a Forge Workspace, make sure you have the "gradlew.bat" file, then simply shift-click your home directory and click "Open command window here". Then type:

```
gradlew.bat setupDecompWorkspace eclipse
```

Or if you're using Intellij (Which I suggest you use over Eclipse):

```
gradlew.bat setupDecompWorkspace idea
```

That should start the process of generating your Workspace.

Surprisingly useful is the fact that it can run multiple commands from one command statement. Meaning that you can type both "setupDecompWorkspace" and "eclipse"/"idea" and it will run both separately one after the other.